# How to carry metadata with data examples and labels in python?

Tags: python, dataset, training, metadata

Is there a pythonic way to carry around metadata that describes the training examples, such that it preserves (i.e., order) after shuffling and splitting (train/test)?

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]) # examples
y = [0,1] # labels
meta = ["Hot day", "Cold day"] # metadata
```

Answer (score 1):

The [shuffle](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.shuffle.html) function in `sklearn.utils` shuffles arrays or sparse matrices in a consistent way.